# Why does the below code stop with exit 1?

Tags: java, linux, bash, ubuntu, sh

I tried to execute a Linux command with the below code.But it doesn't give the output just prints exit 1.When I execute the command on Linux Terminal its giving the output.When execute through Java it gives error.Please advice.

```
JButton btnRunningtime = new JButton("RunningTime");
    btnRunningtime.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try{
                textArea.setText("");
                String s2=comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
                 p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps -eo pid,comm,cmd,start,etime | grep -i "+s2);
                 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                     new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                 while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
                 {
                     textArea.append(s+"\n");
                     System.out.println("Running time "+s);
                 }
                 p.waitFor();
                 System.out.println ("exit: " + p.exitValue());
                 p.destroy();
                 }
             catch(Exception e)
             {
                 System.out.println("Exception "+e);
             }
        }
    });
    btnRunningtime.setBounds(409, 211, 104, 27);
    contentPane.add(btnRunningtime);
```

Comment: `.When execute through Java it gives error` Which error/Exception?

Comment: Or in general, copy/paste the output of the program.

Comment: @TAsk this is all I get as output exit: 1

Comment: @Rogue This is my output: exit: 1
The thing is when I add a line System.out.print("test") after the p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps -eo pid,comm,cmd,start,etime | grep -i "+s2); line, test does get printed. So no error upto that line

Comment: So then this looks like it's running fine. You print out "exit: 1", and 1 is the status from your command. Have you tried running the command yourself?

Comment: @Rogue Yeah.Running the command alone works fine.Its not getting into this line: 
  while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
I don't get it.Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java's `Runtime.exec` method does not invoke a shell to execute the command (so it is different from the standard C `system` call, for example). The command you're trying to pass to `exec` is a shell command, not a simple executable process, and you'll need a shell to get it to work.

What you need to `exec` is something like the array:

```
["sh", "-c", "ps -eo pid,comm,cmd,start,etime | grep -i "+s2]
```

although it's possible that you'll have to specify the first argument as `"/bin/sh"`.

Comment: +1, yes as in windows you have to pass "cmd.exe" , ... to execute commands such as 'dir'

Comment: @rici it works this way!!! but still I don't get the reason.You have said that shell commands cannot be executed this way.But then I have executed the commands like ps -A -o pid,pmap,xlsclients and bash /home/user/Desktop/script.What is the reason those are working? Please advice.

Comment: @user3680477: Most simple shell commands consist of a program name (like `ps`) followed by a list of arguments separated by spaces.  Java's Runtime.exec is clever enough to split the string into a program name and a list of space-separated arguments, and call the operating system function which will execute the command. The shell is much smarter. It can handle redirections (`>` and `<`) and it can execute more than one program at the same time, passing one program's output to the other's input. Runtime.exec is not that smart. So if you need that stuff, you need to run a shell.

Answer (score 1):

you need to read errors also from the process,

use this code

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps -eo pid,comm,cmd,start,etime | grep -i "+s2);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
```

the best approach is to read both, getInputStream and getErrorStream
you can start a thread for each stream to read all responses from the process.
i think you will find out whats going on.

if its not getting to this line `s = br.readLine()` at your current code
thats because no data is sent there,
i think data is redirected to Error stream as there is something wrong happens

**Edit:**

about the error, i think it's because of the parameters passed to the command
i think you need to change them into a String array

```
.exec(new String[]{"ps","-eo","pid,comm,...","|","grep",...});
```

though i am not sure on passing | as param, or some other way